# user-menu in secondary-menu: why?

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks, drupal-zen, drupal-regions

I've created a sub of the zen-theme. And am mighty proud of it, but up in the top right corner (#secondary-menu) the user-menu shows up - perfectly.

I just don't understand how it get's there?

- In structure/blocks the user-menu appears in the Disabled section (Region: None)
- In fact, there IS no region called "secondary-menu" (id of the element gotten from Firebug)

Isn't that strange?

Comment: thank you anonymous, for -1'ing my question without a reason. Very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't comment on your specific template files but the standard Zen page.tpl.php file has this in it:

```
<?php if ($secondary_menu): ?>
  <nav id="secondary-menu" role="navigation">
  <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
      'links' => $secondary_menu,
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => $secondary_menu_heading,
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      ),
    )); ?>
  </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Which should answer how the menu gets printed to the page. If you want to dig one step deeper, the `$secondary_menu` variable is set up in [`template_preprocess_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7).

As to why it's the *user* menu...if you go to `admin/structure/menu/settings` you should see this:

[image]

If you change the secondary link source to something else you should see that reflected in your theme too.

Comment: Aha, Menu settings! I think I understand it now: Main- and Secondary-menu are not "regions" at all. Thank you for a thorough answer, Clive.